# get invalid date and preg_replace it

Tags: php, regex

I have this to replace valid date:

```
$date = preg_replace('~(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})~', '', $date);
```

So dates like this: 08/25/2016 will be replaced.

My problem is, sometimes users write dates like this:

```
082/5/2016
0825/2016
08/252/016
08/25/201
0/85/2016
```

I want to be able to get this too. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not return a message that they didn't put in a valid date format?

Comment: @Daan it is for old data, I want to scan database and replace it. For new values I'm doing it!

Comment: How are you going to correct the dates with typos? E.g. `0/85/2016` could have been `08/15/2016`, `08/05/2016`, `07/25/2016` etc. Are you hopefully swapping to a date column so invalid dates won't populate?

Comment: Use [`'~\b(?=(?:\D*\d){7,8})\d+(?:/\d+)+\b~'`](https://regex101.com/r/uI9xM5/3)

Comment: @chris85 I don't want to correct... just remove from variable!

Comment: @chris85 that's an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have "strings like dates" in your input, you may use a regex with a positive lookbehind to make sure the digits and forward slashes chunk contains 7 to 8 digits and then followed with a word boundary:

```
'~\b(?=(?:\D*\d){7,8}\b)\d+(?:/\d+)+\b~'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI9xM5/4).

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){7,8}\b)` - a lookahead requiring that the word boundary is followed with 7 to 8 digits separated with any amount of non-digits
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:/\d+)+` - 1 or more sequences of `/` + 1 or more digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hOK0AC):

```
$str = "Text containing \n082/5/2016\n0825/2016\n08/252/016\n08/25/201\n0/85/2016\n08/25/2016"; 
$result = preg_replace('~\b(?=(?:\D*\d){7,8})\d+(?:/\d+)+\b~', "", $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: it is really nice, only the `0/85/2016` still not being replaced.

Comment: `0/85/2016` is removed, check the input and output in the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I would validate the date range with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) rather than a regex.

```
$array = array('082/5/2016', '0825/2016', '08/252/016', '08/25/201', '0/85/2016', '08/25/2016');
foreach($array as $key => $date) {
     if(!strtotime($date)) {
         unset($array[$key]); //or handle the invalid date however you want
     }
}
print_r($array);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/628649

Comment: it seems nice! Can I put in this array dates with words? eg: `today is 082/5/2016` will it work?

Comment: Nope, the whole string needs to be the date format. `The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp` Are your dates not separate?